# *nix configuration file storage convention?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, solaris, configuration-files

Might be a candidate for SuperUser, but thought I'd try here first as the question came up for a programming project.

Is there a *nix (targeting Solaris, Linux, and OS X) convention for where system-wide (updateable by all users) configuration information should be stored by an application?

Comment: System-wide and updateable by all users are in some ways competing goals... the conventional paths are usually only root-writeable, or perhaps by a dummy user specifically for a given application.

Comment: To expand on Jefromi's comment, why should another user be able to modify my configuration?

Comment: @Jefromi Indeed.  That's the problem.  :-)  I have a unique circumstance where certain items are shared, but need to be updated by any user of the system.

Comment: Are these items by any chance updated through the application? Or are they pure pre-run configuration? In some cases of the former, there are games you can play with running a daemon as an application user, and letting users do what they need to through the daemon.

Comment: Through the app.  It's a cross-platform java app, really trying to not generate too much platform dependent code, but will consider it if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the most common scheme is to have a system-wide configuration in `/etc/app_name` and the user can create `~/.app_name` which overrides settings in `/etc/app_name`. One can even go one step further and do it with a three layer concept: for example, if your app is in `/opt/app_name`, then have a default config `/opt/app_name/conf`, and both `/etc/app_name` and `~/.app_name` can override it.

IIRC, KDE uses this three layer concept and has even possibilities to mark sections or keys as non-overridable so a sys-admin can disallow a user to override e. g. the position of the task-bar. Probably overkill to implement, but maybe food for thought.

Whether the configuration is stored in a directory containing several files or is just one file doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

Mostly configuration information stored in the `/etc/<app name>` folder or if it is a user specific configuration it is usually stored in the `~/.<app name>` folder.

Comment: I think that `/etc` may be as close to standard as you're going to get. The expectation is that it's restricted access - you might at least want to add the users in question to a group for your application, and make it group- but not world-writeable.

Comment: Does OS X follow this convention too, or is the "Libraries" structure more appropriate?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not have an experience with MacOS, but basically this is Unix and it should be about the same

Answer (score 1):

Solaris (SVR4) standard is for the application binaries (files that do not change) to go under /opt/*appname*, files with a varying size (eg. logs) to go under /var/opt/*appname*, and system wide configuration files to go under /etc/opt/*appname*. User's customization goes traditionally in/under ~/.*appname*.